# Regex: negative lookbehind not directly before target

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am debugging some JavaScript code and I need to identify lines that contain " = " followed by a comparison operator such as "==", ">", "<", "!=".  However, I want to ignore lines that are preceded by the start of a for loop.  So I want to identify lines like this:

`x = (y > z) * 2;`

but ignore lines like this:

`for (var i = 1; i<5; i++) {`

This would require a negative lookbehind, I believe.  But the text "for ", which I would put in the negative lookbehind, does not immediately precede the text I want to match.

I tried this regular expression in Notepad++:

`(?<!for .*) = .*(==|>|<|!=)`

but it was reported as "invalid" because a quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it a non fixed width.

On the other hand, this regex works but doesn't help me because "for " does not immediately precede the text I want to match:

`(?<!for ) = .*(==|>|<|!=)`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*for ).* = .*(==|>|<|!=)
```

If you don't want to match the "for" part, throw in another capture group, and access / replace on that group

```
^(?!.*for ).* (= .*(?:==|>|<|!=))
```

A bit more robust (tolerant of absent whitespace, and `<=` + `>=`, but digusting):

```
^(?!.*?\bfor\b).*?[^\n!<>=](=[^\n=].*?(?:[<>]|[!=<>]=))
```

EDIT:

I had to insert `^`, to assure the match started at the beginning of the line. Depending on your regex flavor, `^` may match the beginning of a line or beginning of the text in its entirely. If its the latter, you'd have to use something like `(?<=^|\n)`, a positive lookbehind, instead of `^` (which works in your case for Notepad++).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Unfortunately a line like the following, which includes a for loop, still matches:

```for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {```

Comment: @CurtisD ah, you're right-  I forgot I need to anchor it to the beginning of the line. See my edit